# MySql "Preparing" costs too much time

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I am new to MySQL performance analysis. I find a join query in my system becomes slow recently (3.52s for ~4 tables, each table has ~1000-2000 rows). And I viewed the performance analysis with phpmyadmin. The result is shown below:

> 1  Starting    170 µs
>   2  Opening Tables  44 µs
>   3  System Lock 7 µs
>   4  Table Lock  7 µs
>   5  Init    65 µs
>   6  Optimizing  20 µs
>   7  Statistics  92 µs
>   8  Preparing   31 µs
>   9  Creating Tmp Table  236 µs
>   10 Executing   2 µs
>   11 Copying To Tmp Table    68 µs
>   12 Optimizing  10 µs
>   13 Statistics  14 µs
>   **14   Preparing   3.5 s**
>   15 Creating Sort Index 2.6 ms
>   16 Copying To Group Table  15.9 ms
>   17 Sorting Result  2.1 ms
>   18 Sending Data    391 µs
>   19 End 7 µs
>   20 Removing Tmp Table  1.3 ms
>   21 End 3 µs
>   22 Removing Tmp Table  819 µs
>   23 End 10 µs
>   24 Query End   2 µs
>   25 Freeing Items   20 µs
>   26 Removing Tmp Table  6 µs
>   27 Freeing Items   365 µs
>   28 Logging Slow Query  3 µs
>   29 Cleaning Up 6 µs

I don't understand why the `Preparing` phase costs 3.5s. How can I reduce it?

Comment: FYI, the states are described here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/general-thread-states.html. Preparing means _This state occurs during query optimization._

Comment: I hate to make comments like I'm about to but here goes - `preparing` costs you 3.5 seconds because it's *slow*. But you already knew that. So, in order to determine why something's slow, you provide people you ask (us) with information that help us help you. Information that you have to provide is table structure (so we can see indexes and storage engine), output of `EXPLAIN` along with the query you're running and MySQL configuration.

Comment: @Barmar it is useful for me to understand this (actually I did want to ask what does "prepare" exactly mean. Thanks.

Comment: @N.B. Thanks for your hints. I just wanted to firstly check the rough direction to trace into this problem. And I now know EXPLAIN can help some. I located the major time-consuming part and an exact question is asked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29960821/mysql-in-where-is-slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to throw a wild guess in my answer, **you probably don't use any index**.

In SQL Optimization, [Indexing is a broken cheat](http://use-the-index-luke.com/), like the `konami-code` in `contra`, or the `doors` in `age of empire`.

Anyway, try putting some indexing in your database, then come back to us, and be amazed by how fast your preparing phase goes now.

Comment: I use primary and unique indexes for some columns, but it seems not enough (at least not enough for my query). I located the major part of preparing time and open a new question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29960821/mysql-in-where-is-slow. Please have a look. Thanks.