# MySQL "in-where" is slow?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables: `Posts` and `Tags`, which stores user's posting articles and the tags they attached to the articles. A table `PostTags` is used to indicate the relationship of article IDs and tag IDs. The structures are as below:

**Posts:**

```
id | title | author_id | create_time | update_time | ... #(title, author_id, create_time) is unique
```

**Tags:**

```
id | tag_text | create_time #tag_text is unique and index
```

**PostTags:**

```
id | post_id | tag_id #(post_id, tag_id) is unique
```

I now use the following sql to get the articles with corresponding tags (using group_concat).

```
SELECT p.id, p.title, t.tag AS Tags FROM Posts p 
LEFT JOIN Tags t on t.id IN 
    (SELECT tag_id FROM PostTags WHERE post_id=s.id) 
GROUP BY p.id ORDER BY p.update_time DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

But I find it very slow (for 2.5k rows of articles and 600 tags, it takes >3s). How can I improve the performance?

The EXPLAIN result is as follows:

```
id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra

1 | PRIMARY | p | ALL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 2569 | Using temporary; Using filesort

1 | PRIMARY | t | ALL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 616   

2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | PostTags | index_subquery | unique_index,tag_id,post_id | 
tag_id | 4 | func | 1 | Using where
```

PS, my original sql is (with group_concat)

```
SELECT p.id, p.title, group_concat(DINSTINCT t.tag) AS Tags FROM Posts p 
LEFT JOIN Tags t on t.id IN 
    (SELECT tag_id FROM PostTags WHERE post_id=s.id) 
GROUP BY p.id ORDER BY p.update_time DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

But the case without group_concat is same.

Comment: where you use group_concat in your query???

Comment: Oops, originally I thought group_concat will has impact; but during my posting this question, I tried the case without group_concat but find it still slow. So some inconsistency in this question. Just edited.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[MySQL documentation describes exactly this kind of situation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/subquery-restrictions.html):

> A typical case for poor IN subquery performance is when the subquery returns a small number of rows but the outer query returns a large number of rows to be compared to the subquery result.
>
> The problem is that, for a statement that uses an IN subquery, the optimizer rewrites it as a correlated subquery. [..] **If the inner and outer queries return M and N rows, respectively, the execution time becomes on the order of O(M×N), rather than O(M+N) as it would be for an uncorrelated subquery**.

Using another join instead of a subquery would be a more optimal solution:

```
SELECT p.id, p.title, t.tag AS Tags FROM Posts p
LEFT JOIN PostTags pt on pt.post_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN Tags t on t.id = pt.tag_id
GROUP BY p.id ORDER BY p.update_time DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

Comment: Yes. That's 0.03s now. Thanks~

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query with `group_concat` and `group_concat` has nothing to 
do with the speed.

```
select
p.id,
p.title,
group_concat(t.tag_text) as post_tags
from Post p 
left join PostTags pt on pt.post_id = p.id
left join Tags t on pt.tag_id = t.id
group by p.id
order by p.udate_time desc 
limit 0,10
```

You already have some indexes on the table which is so far good, however adding another 
index will boost up the query

```
alter table Posts add index updated_time_idx(updated_time);
```